# RecyclerView new items adding issue

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView, it has 30 items and when I scroll to the end to load another 30 items, it goes to the first item.

I tried to get current visible item then scroll to it when new items are added

```
((LinearLayoutManager) recyclerview1.getLayoutManager()).scrollToPositionWithOffset(layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition(), 0);
```

But it is not that smooth.
I tried to scroll to `listmap.size()` but it will force the RecyclerView to scroll to the end of the list (if the user scrolled up).

I have seen some apps when I scroll to the bottom, new items are added smoothly that I can't even notice that the change is made.

I need a solution, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm posting the solution here thanks to Vastal.
This code to avoid my main problem in the question:

```
recyclerview.getAdapter().notifyItemInserted(detailsList.size() -1);
```

And this one to load more items. Should be added in onScroll:

```
if (!recyclerview.canScrollVertically(1)) {
    _loadMore();
}
```